# How to create/delate/displace an issue in jira Kanban using C#?

Tags: c#, jira, jira-rest-api

It’s possible to control / update a jira kanban board using c# with librarys like attlasian.sdk or  techtalk/JiraRestClient , 
How to create/delate/displace an issue in jira Kanban using C# ?

Comment: You should really start to read the JIRA info first, and ask a question about what you are having trouble with.

Comment: in jira how can I update issuestatus with rest api in c# ?
issuestatus :allow  to make a issue transition

Comment: staticvoid Main(string[] args)
{
    //
  Jira jr = newJira(“http://localhost:8080", “username”, “password”);
 
  Issue issue = jr.GetIssue(“Issue-2”);
 
  issue.Resolution = “Won’t Fix”;
 
  issue.WorkflowTransition(WorkflowActions.Resolve);
 
  issue.SaveChanges();
}

Comment: but the code does not work. :(

Answer (score 1):

> **It’s possible to control / update a jira kanban board using c#**  : YES
>    it is. Rest API can help you do that. How to create/delate/displace an
>
> **issue in jira Kanban using C#** : Write some code, show us what you did.

Comment: in jira how can I update issuestatus with rest api in c# ?
issuestatus :allow  to make a issue transition